# Facebook page plugin doesn't show in HTML page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to insert the facebook page plugin in html page and i am following this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin
This is how i insert the code in the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>CNN</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/cnn" data-width="300" data-height="200" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/cnn"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/cnn">CNN</a></blockquote></div></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

But the page plugin doesn't show. Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i tested the script locally and that's why it didn't worked. I uploaded the html page on a server and it worked.